# Adding margin to relative layout doesn't work with Android API 19 Kitkat4.4.2

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin.android

I applied a margin to a relative layout using this snippet :

**WaitingView.cs**

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linearParams.setMargins(0, 80, 0, 0);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(linearParams);
relativeLayout.requestLayout();
```

It works like a charm on all my devices but not on the Samsung Galaxy S4 Kitkat 4.4.2 API 19.

**WaitingViewLayout.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/WaitingViewActivityIndicator"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Is there a way to make it works with API 19 ?

Answer (score 0):

Well the reason they are not working is quite simple you are providing `RelativeLayout` the layout params of a `LinearLayout` try something like this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
lParams.AddRule(LayoutRules.CenterHorizontal)
```

In case this does not work for you feel free to revert

Also, note that this is Xamarin code so you might have to convert it a little here and there.

Good luck.